# Query from massive DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB (over 300GB of data) that updates daily and id like to select specific data from the most recent entries. A direct "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x" takes over minimum 30 mins to return values. The rows are incremented daily in their "DATA_SET_ID" column, after searching a lot and reading stack overflow posts i came up with the following query which gives me an error. can someone help me out with this query? or maybe give me a better and faster way of getting the data?

```
WITH tbl AS (
SELECT INDEX_RIC, RIC, TOTAL_SHARES, MAX(DATA_SET_ID)
FROM DB.MASSIVE_TABLE
GROUP BY INDEX_RIC, RIC, TOTAL_SHARES
WHERE TOTAL_SHARES > 0)    

SELECT tbl.INDEX_RIC, tbl.RIC
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.RIC in ('ABC.DE')
```

Data Sample:

[image]

Expected output:

Rows with TOTAL_SHARES value of greater than 0, from rows with the highest DATA_SET_ID, and where its RIC is in the stated RICs in the second part of the query. The output should only contain RIC and INDEX_RIC column.

columns TOTAL_SHARES and DATA_SET_ID added to the screenshot below to give a better idea of the desired output.

[image]

Error:

[image]

EDITS:

- DB is a mysql DB.
- im running the script in HeidiSQL to test but it will move to my python script for further processing.

Thank you!!

Comment: ORDER BY timestamp (or ID) DESC LIMIT 50?

Comment: What's the error? Timeout ? please publish in full

Comment: @jarlh the thing is i need every single row that meets the conditions , im sending the query from a python script that then does some processing to the received data.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: @P.Salmon unfortunately i cant copy/paste the message from Heidi so i added a screenshot of it!

Comment: @jarlh is it really necessary for me to put my python script here?

Comment: No python code needed, just the SQL, together with sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here.  You have total_shares in the select of your CTE, but you aren't grouping or aggregating with it.  You have double quotes around strings in your second query.

Comment: @jarlh unfortunately i dont have publishing rights on the data and i cant post it here

Comment: @Andrew my apologies, im very new to sql. i changed the double quotes and still the same error. The thing about total_shares  is that its a unique number of shares each indR (INDEX_RIC) has and all i need is to make sure im working with the lines that dont have 0 value for it. do i  need to do something extra with it?

Comment: Hi - it’s not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to run a SQL statement like “SELECT * FROM table WHERE x" ? If so, please update your question to show just that actual statement and also include the EXPLAIN PLAN for it

Comment: @NickW i have put my sql query statement in my post along with a screenshot of the error i get and what id like to get from the query. I also updated my expected output.

Comment: Your GROUP BY needs to include all the columns in your SELECT that aren’t being aggregated

Comment: @NickW still the same error

Comment: If you can’t supply sample data (it doesn’t have to be actual data) it makes it difficult to understand what you are doing and therefore to help you. For example, what does “ rows with the highest DATA_SET_ID” mean? Are you getting a single new DATA_SET_ID value every day and do you just want records with that value? Are there versions of records that don’t get updated every day so the DATA_SET_ID you want to select could change from record to record?

Comment: @NickW added samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CTE, the WHERE clause needs to be before the GROUP BY clause:

```
WITH tbl AS (
SELECT indR, RIC, TOTAL_SHARES, MAX(DATA_SET_ID)
FROM DB.MASSIVE_TABLE
WHERE TOTAL_SHARES > 0
GROUP BY indR, RIC, TOTAL_SHARES)    

SELECT tbl.indR, tbl.RIC
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.RIC in ('security', 'security1', 'security2', ...)
```

A simpler version of this, based on the updated question, would be:

```
SELECT DATA_SET_ID, INDEX_RIC, RIC, TOTAL_SHARES
FROM DB.MASSIVE_TABLE
WHERE TOTAL_SHARES > 0
AND RIC in ('ABC.DE')
AND DATA_SET_ID = (
   SELECT MAX(DATA_SET_ID) FROM DB.MASSIVE_TABLE
)
;
```

Comment: Same error again